# R: Can not change the font size of title of graph, legend, and axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I would like to change the font size of title, legend, and axes of a graph, I changed it using theme but it doesn't have any affect :

```
ggplot( data = df.m, aes(x=variable, y=value , na.rm = TRUE)) + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(fill=label), outlier.size = 0.5) + 
  labs(x="",y="Values",fill="") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=100), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, colour = 'black'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=100) , text=element_text(size=100), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 100), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 100), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 100), legend.position = "top") + theme_bw()
```

Why it does not change the font size at all?

Comment: theme_bw() is resetting everything, put it before