# resize text of legends, label of axes and units of axes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How to change the size of text for legends, label of the axes and also the size of text unit (on the axes)  in following script.

```
MYPLOT<-map_df(Totallist,function(x) data.frame(MAE = x), .id = "row") %>% 
  mutate(
    row = as.numeric(row) - 1,
    Size= floor(row / 8+1) %>% as.factor,
    Materials= (row %% 8) %>% as.factor) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(Size, MAE, fill=Materials), position = "dodge")
MYPLOT+ theme_bw()
levels(MYPLOT$data$Materials) <- c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8")
MYPLOT
```

I was using [this link](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014372/r-can-not-change-the-font-size-of-title-of-graph-legend-and-axes), which I was not successful

Appericiate!

Comment: Changing the base text size within the chosen theme will change all text sizing in your graph `theme_bw(base_size = 24)`

Comment: Thanks @JanBoyer. Another minor question, If I want to change the format of sclae for Y-axis, how I can do that? By now, the scale is 100 by 100 but i need something like 20 by 20.